# Compare row with other rows in the same table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have the below records in my table,

[image: Table]

If the HoleNumber combination is not having 'A' and 'B' for the particular datetime, we need to remove the alphabets from the number.
i.e., Remove 'A' from third record and sixth record. Because, it doesn't have B combinations for that datetime.

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [SQL tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: You can join a table to itself by giving each instance of the table a different alias. (`select * From [Table] a INNER JOIN [Table] b on a.Field = b.Field`). But the question is still not clear... there **ARE** `B` combinations at that datetime. If the sequencing matters, you probably also want a `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function with PARTITIONs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from myTable
where id in
(
select id from myTable t1
inner join
(
select [date],  left([holeNumber], len(holeNumber)-1) as hNumber
from myTable
group by [date], left([holeNumber], len(holeNumber)-1)
having count(holeNumber) = 1
) tmp
on t1.[date] = tmp.[date] and left(t1.holeNumber, len(holeNumber)-1) = tmp.hNumber);
```

would do it, provided your requirements are strictly to remove having only 1 type of holeNumber.

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0250357d828b1bc6cbfed02c605beaad)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Its better to avoid the code "left([holeNumber],1)" to take the integer, because the holenumber goes upto 18A,18B.

Comment: @BharathiMohan, it is not a problem, you can change it to read left(holeNumber, len(holeNumber-1)). I will edit for you.